# How/Why does SonarQube count so many conditions for a simple `if` statement?

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

See image below. It's just a simple `if` statement (Typescript here). `if (row)`. How does SonarQube arrive at the determination that there are 4 conditions here???

[image]

The full structure is:

```
if (row) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

`row` is a typed object. By the typedef, it can't be null or undefined.

And it's not just this super-simple case but many other kinds of cases. It seems like the condition count is always too high.